# Is there a .NET library that can convert PNG files to PDF?

Tags: .net, pdf, png

I have an application where I need to convert PNG files PDF on the fly.  Is there an existing library that will do this?  I would like the PDF to look exactly like the PNG--no extra margins, no borders, etc.

I'm using .NET 4.0.

EDIT: I tried iTextSharp and it worked great.  Here's the basic code to get what I needed.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

public class ITextPDFHelper
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ITextPDFHelper.CreatePDF("C:\\temp\test.pdf", "C:\\temp\test.png");
    }

    public static void CreatePDF(string fileToCreate, pngFileName)
    {
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(fileToCreate, FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        Image png = Image.GetInstance(pngFileName);
        png.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        doc.Add(png);
        doc.Close();
    }//CreatePDF
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be a scenario for such a requirement? In my opinion, PNG is the more "open" format that is readable by a broader range of clients. So putting it into a PDF acutally locks it down (which can be a possible scenario on its own...).

Comment: @Uwe -- I have an app where I dynamically generate PNG files.  I want to put them in a "final" format for my end users.  I'm basically creating pamphlets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean, a pdf document containing a single page with your picture in it? Take a look at [ITextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Comment: Wouldn't that add `extra margins` or `borders`?

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) is how I would usually do something like this...so check out [ImageMagick.NET](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/).

I'm not familiar with ImageMagick.NET's syntax, but with ImageMagick, this is the command you would use:

```
convert source.png dest.pdf
```

As you can see, it's relatively simple.

Answer (score 0):

For various PDF operations, I am using [Aspose.Pdf](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) and related products like [Aspose.Pdf.Kit](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/default.aspx).

I think it is not the most direct solution but it should be usable to achieve your desired result.