# How to convert google 3D Bar chart to image in .net?

Tags: .net, google-visualization

I have used google api http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/columnchart_old.html to show 3d Bar chart to user but now I want to export that to pdf for that I need the image of that chart so can any one help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you send an URL to the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/chart/) and it returns you an image.

So basically you have to programmatically issue a [`WebRequest`](http://www.google.com/search?q=WebRequest) and store the returned image as an image file (or in memory).

To actually convert an image file (e.g. a PNG) to a PDF, please see [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564260/is-there-a-net-library-that-can-convert-png-files-to-pdf).

Comment: Thanks for help. But I have used visualization chart and  I did not find any help from google for image support in Visualization 3D Bar chart to image conversion...help me out in this.

Comment: You are refering to something like this: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/areachart.html right? I'm not sure whether/how you can access this, since it is rendered as SVG/VML. Maybe you could fake an old browser by the user agent string and force Google to downgrad the result by using actual images, again?

Comment: I am using this http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/columnchart_old.html as my requirement. I need to take this as image for export to pdf.